# PHP: How to merge the values of associative array whose keys are same?

Tags: php

Hi i have built a form through bootstrap form builder which is having two checkbox groups where first group is having 6 check-boxes & second is having 5 check-boxes. When i fill the form the values posted in following manner.

```
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244583705#reading": "Reading"
},
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244603527#sports": "Sports"
},
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244603819#dancing": "Dancing"
},
{
  "Hobbies#142872842446043#watching_tv": "Watching TV"
},
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244614612#swimming": "Swimming"
},
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244611702#meeting_new_people": "Meeting new people"
},
{
  "Education#14287284244615059#bachelors": "BAchelors"
},
{
  "Education#14287284244629279#masters": "MAsters"
},
{
  "Education#1428728424462974#ms": "MS"
},
{
  "Education#14287284244629849#surgeon": "Surgeon"
},
{
  "Education#14287284244622498#matric": "Matric"
}
```

for now i am storing this in my mongodb database as $key = $value. But i am getting problem while showing it in grid view.

I tried grouping it with all possible ways but couldnt get the easy way as the code is getting too complicated if the checkbox groups increases. Is there any function in php which merges the values if keys are same??

final output should be like:

```
{ "Hobbies":"Reading, Sports, Dancing.....(so on)},
{ "Education":"Masters, .... "}
```

for the above key side. currently all keys are different but i can compare with by explode function probably explode[0]

Comment: Why not create form with checkboxes using arrays? I mean <input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies[14287284244611702]" value="Reading"> and then work with it in PHP?

Comment: If i'm good understing you, you dont want to group on the key but on a part of the key, which is less easy. (and btw, i don't think there is such a function, you have to write your own.)

Comment: yes you are right the combination of key is for uniqueness of each checkbox as the user may enter same values for two checkboxes or same naming to two groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use array naming in your HTML code for all the hobbies checkboxes as follows:

`<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies[] value="Reading"/><label>Reading</label>"
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies[] value="Sports"/><label>Sports</label>"...`

in a same way you can do for Education checkboxes.

Now when you would `print_r($_POST['Hobbies'])`. This would provide you the required output.

Comment: wow...thats amazing....i got what i need i was wasting time building logic just because of not nkowing this one thanks a lot

Comment: pleasure is all mine helping you

Answer (score 0):

I think Ashwani is right, but if still want to group your object on the key first element, you can do it this way:

```
$a = json_decode('[{
  "Hobbies#14287284244583705#reading": "Reading"
},
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244603527#sports": "Sports"
},
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244603819#dancing": "Dancing"
},
{
  "Hobbies#142872842446043#watching_tv": "Watching TV"
},
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244614612#swimming": "Swimming"
},
{
  "Hobbies#14287284244611702#meeting_new_people": "Meeting new people"
},
{
  "Education#14287284244615059#bachelors": "BAchelors"
},
{
  "Education#14287284244629279#masters": "MAsters"
},
{
  "Education#1428728424462974#ms": "MS"
},
{
  "Education#14287284244629849#surgeon": "Surgeon"
},
{
  "Education#14287284244622498#matric": "Matric"
}]', true);

$hash = array();
$out = array();
foreach($a as $n => $nod) $hash[explode('#',key($nod), 2)[0]][] = $nod[key($nod)];
foreach($hash as $k => $v) $out[$k] = implode(',', $v);
var_dump($out);
```